# How to achieve concurrency benefits with gevent (combined with uwsgi)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, gevent

I'm trying to understand how to achieve the async benefits that `gevent`'s monkey patching is supposed to provide.

To test this, I created a test server.

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask
from time import sleep
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)


def fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.route('/sleep/<int:n>')
def sleep_view(n):
    sleep(n)
    return f'Slept {n}'


@app.route('/slowreq')
def slowreq_view():
    res = requests.get('http://localhost:8002/sleep/5')
    return 'From another server: ' + res.text


@app.route('/fib/<int:n>')
def fib_view(n):
    x = fib(n)
    return str(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    port = 8001
    threaded = False
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        port = int(sys.argv[1])
        threaded = True
    print(f'Threaded is {threaded}')
    app.run(port=port, threaded=threaded)
```

If I run it in two processes, first with `python3 test.py` (runs on 8001, flask is non-threaded, but monkey patched) and then `python3 test.py 8002` (runs on 8002, flask is threaded, also monkey patched), I expect the following to happen:

1. In two terminals, I quickly run `time curl http://localhost:8001/slowreq` one after the other. `/slowreq` calls `/sleep/5` on the other server, so as a standalone request, it should take 5 seconds.
2. Server on 8001 receives the request and calls the 8002 server with `requests.get`. Requests is a wrapper on `urllib3`, which is a stdlib wrapper on `socket`, which `gevent.monkey.patch_all()` patches by default (`socket=True` is default). Because of the monkey-patching, I *expect* the server to be waiting on the response.
3. The 8002 server receives the `/sleep/5` request, sleeps for 5 seconds, and responds. Because it is a threaded server, multiple sleeps can occur at the same time.

In the non-monkey patched case, I expect the first `/slowreq` request to take 5 seconds, and the second one to take 10 seconds, and that is what I see.

However, in the monkey-patched case, I expect the 8001 server to no longer block on the `requests.get` call, and thus both requests would take 5 seconds. This is not what happens, and the behavior is identical to the non-monkey-patched case.

Thus, my question is: what does the monkey patching achieve, and how can I take advantage of its benefits?

Comment: If you want to use gevent you will need to use a [gevent based WSGI server](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#gevent). The simple built-in development server will not run in a gevent loop.

Comment: @KlausD. Do you have an example usage by chance? Running `pipenv run uwsgi --wsgi run:app --gevent 100 --http :8000` does not fix the issue - the two requests still take a total of 10 seconds.